# How to get ProcessBuilder to handle nested quotes?

Tags: java, windows, process, cmd, processbuilder

I am having problems getting [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) to execute a command-line the same way as the cmd.exe console.

1. The command line is:
   `show_parameters.bat jdk-1_5_0_22-windows-i586-p.exe /s /v"/qn INSTALLDIR=\"C:\Program Files (x86)\gili\""`
2. The batch file `show_parameters.bat` (below) shows the tokens that cmd.exe breaks the command-line into.
3. `Testcase.java` (below) attempts to execute the same command-line as #1 using ProcessBuilder.
4. If you run `show_parameters.bat jdk-1_5_0_22-windows-i586-p.exe /s /v"/qn INSTALLDIR=\"C:\Program Files (x86)\gili\""` you will get:

   ```
   Console tokens:

   jdk-1_5_0_22-windows-i586-p.exe
   /s
   /v"/qn INSTALLDIR=\"C:\Program
   Files
   (x86)\gili\""
   ```
5. If you run `java Testcase` you will get:

   ```
   Java tokens: [cmd.exe, /c, show_parameters.bat, jdk-1_5_0_22-windows-i586-p.exe,
    /s, /v"/qn INSTALLDIR=\"C:\Program Files (x86)\gili\""]

   Console tokens:

   jdk-1_5_0_22-windows-i586-p.exe
   /s
   "/v"/qn
   INSTALLDIR
   \"C:\Program Files (x86)\gili\"
   ""
   ```

**Is it possible to cause ProcessBuilder to produce the same tokenization as #1?** Or is this a bug in Java?

---

#### show_parameters.bat

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

    echo.
    echo Console tokens:
    echo.

    :again
    if [%1] == [] goto end
      echo %1
      shift
      goto again
    :end
```

#### Testcase.java

```java
import java.io.*;

public class Testcase
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
        String base = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\gili";
        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", "show_parameters.bat", "jdk-1_5_0_22-windows-i586-p.exe", "/s",
                "/v\"/qn INSTALLDIR=\\\"" + base + "\\\"\"");
        processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
        System.out.println("Java tokens: " + processBuilder.command());
        Process process = processBuilder.start();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        while (true)
        {
            String line = in.readLine();
            if (line == null)
                break;
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try that way:

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", "show_parameters.bat jdk-1_5_0_22-windows-i586-p.exe /s /v\"/qn INSTALLDIR=\\\"" + base + "\\\"\"");
```

or

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", "show_parameters.bat jdk-1_5_0_22-windows-i586-p.exe /s /v\"/qn INSTALLDIR='" + base + "'\"");
```

"/c" is expecting one argument only - the command which will be executed in the CMD

Comment: Wow. I can't believe that was the problem! Thanks for the keen eye!